# Silverlight - Changing button text color created dynamically

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am trying to change a button text color of dynamically created buttons on a Silverlight form using ViewModel. The problem I face is, when I change the color of a button text, all the buttons will get effected. Since, the buttons are dynamically created, I can't have a control on it.

I was suggested to write a ForegroundColor property into Model and then attach to the button, I tried as you see in code, but couldn't do much about it.

Could you see as what I am doing and help me with your suggestions as I am not sure, I am doing it right way.

Thanks

**Model**

```
namespace Web.Models
{
  [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
  public class Sales
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int SalesId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ShowOrder { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Regurgitate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ForegroundColor { get; set; }

    public Sales(Salese result)
    {
        SalesId = result.SalesId;
        ShowOrder = result.ShowOrder;
        Active = result.Active;
        Regurgitate = result.Regurgitate;            

        if (SalesId == 12)
        {
            var bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(ForegroundColor);
            Color btnColor = Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

            SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(btnColor);
        }
   }
}
```

}

**ViewModel**

```
private Brush _foregroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black); 

public override void Loaded()
{
    OnMainOutcome();
}


public Brush ForegroundColor
{
   get { return _foregroundColor; }
   set
   {
       if (_foregroundColor == value) return;
       _foregroundColor = value;                

       OnPropertyChanged("ForegroundColor");
    }
 }

 private void OnMainOutcome()
 {
    var selectedSalesId = (int)OutcomeCommand.CommandParameter;
    CurrentSubOutcomes = GetCurrentSubOutcomes(selectedSalesId);

    foreach (var index in CurrentOutcomes)
    {
       if (index.OutcomeId == 12)        
          ForegroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
       else
          ForegroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
 }
```

**XAML Edited**

```
 <controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
    <converters:NumericToColorConverter x:Key="NumericToColorConverter"/>
</controls:ChildWindow.Resources>

 <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" MinHeight="200" Width="160" Margin="2,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentOutcomes}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Button Height="30" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Outcome}" CommandParameter="{Binding SalesOutcomeId }" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=OutcomeCommand}" Foreground="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Converter={StaticResource NumericToColorConverter}, Path=ForegroundColor}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

**Converter Class NEW**

```
  using System;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows;

  namespace Converters
  {
      public class NumericToColorConverter : IValueConverter
      {
        static readonly SolidColorBrush RED_BRUSH = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        static readonly SolidColorBrush BLUE_BRUSH = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           //Int32 id = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);

           //LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush();
           //brush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 1);
           //brush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 0);
           //brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop()
           //{
           //    Color = Colors.White,
           //    Offset = 0
           //});
           //brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop()
           //{            
           //    Color = Color.FromArgb(
           //        200,
           //        System.Convert.ToByte((id * 103) % 256),
           //        System.Convert.ToByte((id * 157) % 256),
           //        System.Convert.ToByte((id * 233) % 256)
           //    ),
           //    Offset = 1
           //});

           //return brush;
           var OutcomeId = (int)value;

           if (OutcomeId == 12)
           {
              return RED_BRUSH;
           }
           else
           {
              return BLUE_BRUSH;
           }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind the `Foreground` to a value on a `StaticResource` so all buttons will bind to this same value.

You can either create a specific "ButtonForegroundConverter" or you can add the Brush property to the item level viewmodel that also has the `Outcome` property which you already bind to the `Content` of the button. Then the button xaml will look something like this:

```
<Button ...
        Content="{Binding Outcome}" 
        Foreground="{Binding OutcomeForegroundBrush}" 
        ...
        />
```

If you are binding directly to an entity, then adding properties like that would not be a good idea, so the example above assumes you have a intermediate viewmodel or controller on which you could add properties like that.

If you choose to use a converter it would look something like this:

```
<Button ...
        Content="{Binding Outcome}" 
        Foreground="{Binding OutcomeId, Converter={StaticResource OutcomeToForegroundConverter}}" 
        ...
        />
```

And the converter:

```
namespace MyConverters {

    public sealed class OutcomeToColorConverter : IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {

            // We must have a valid integer value, double check bindings
            if (value == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value", 
                    "Please make sure the value is not null.");
            }

            var OutcomeId = (int)value;

            if (OutcomeId == XXX) { 
                return RED_BRUSH; 
            }
            else {
                return BLUE_BRUSH;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        static readonly SolidColorBrush RED_BRUSH = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        static readonly SolidColorBrush BLUE_BRUSH = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }
}
```

Remember to declare the resource:

```
<myconverters:OutcomeToForegroundConverter x:Key="OutcomeToForegroundConverter" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Actually, after posting this question, I tried implementing the same way but in the converter class it gives error on `(int)value` as specific cast is Invalid. Why is that? I am updating the above source, with the code I have got similar to you. Please have a look and suggest.

Comment: Well, an `int` cannot be cast from `null`. I you will have to fix the binding so that you always get a non-null value, or change the converter to check for `null` first. Please check that the value is **binding** correctly. TIP: look at your OUTPUT window for text that would indicate any binding errors with more specific information.

Comment: Can I bind my model object (class) as a parameter to converter and access its value? I am having trouble to pass the value to converter and evaluate against the converter, because its not able to recognize the parameter which I pass. I tried almost every value to bind, though I don't get any error now but I will not able to evaluate in the converter class. Any suggestions? Also, can I debug the converter class, so that I can see what actually is passing there?

Comment: Sure you can debug the `Converter`. Put a breakpoint inside the functions by clicking where you want to stop, and press **F9**. Then run again to see the code stop there. Passing the object as a parameter is also possible, however I think if you start debugging at the breakpoint inside your converter, and look at the Output, you will probably see that there are problems with the binding that you can fix. When you stop there, look at the values inside the **locals** window too. (as well as the output window for a LOG)

Comment: thanks for all that inputs, I have solved the issue now. All I did is removed `Source={StaticResource ViewModel}` from the button binding and worked nicely after that, but I still don't understand, how did it make the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your listbox displays a list of `Sales`, but each item is templated to bind button foreground to single property in the VM. Create `MyBrush` property in your `Sales` class and bind to it.

```
namespace Web.Models
{
  [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
  public class Sales
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int SalesId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ShowOrder { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Regurgitate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ForegroundColor { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SolidColorBrush MyBrush { get; set; }

    public Sales(Salese result)
    {
        SalesId = result.SalesId;
        ShowOrder = result.ShowOrder;
        Active = result.Active;
        Regurgitate = result.Regurgitate;            

        if (SalesId == 12)
        {
            var bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(ForegroundColor);
            Color btnColor = Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

            MyBrush = new SolidColorBrush(btnColor);

        }
   }
}
```

---

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" MinHeight="200" Width="160" Margin="2,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentOutcomes}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Button Height="30" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Outcome}" CommandParameter="{Binding SalesOutcomeId }" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=OutcomeCommand}" Foreground="{Binding MyBrush}"  />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I tried your code snippet, but nothing happens, it don't invoke the the MyBrush Property and gives error 'The remote server returned an error: NotFound.'. Why is tht?

Comment: but when I comment the line ` //[DataMember]
        //public SolidColorBrush MyBrush { get; set; }` the error goes, and nothing happens, meaning the button text remains same.

Comment: maybe `SolidColorBrush` has problem being serialized. You can try storing the color value as simple type and use `IValueConverter` with binding.